# Unable to do POS (part-of-speech) tagging using Spacy

Tags: spacy

I managed to load as

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm-3.5.0")
```

but when i run the 2nd line i.e. `ans = nlp('this is a test string')`; I get error on this line which is "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

I have followed the exact documentation and do not see any tuple here as input; what is the error?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @user155105, welcome to the site. If you find the answers to your question useful, please consider upvoting them. Also, please consider accepting one (with the tick mark ✓ next to it) if you consider it correct or, alternatively, please describe in a comment why you consider it incorrect or not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The name `en_core_web_sm-3.5.0` is not a valid name for a model. This works perfectly fine:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ans = nlp('this is a test string')
```

Of course, you need to download the model first (e.g. `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`)

Then, if we want to actually compute named entities:

```
ans = nlp("I called Tom to let him know I was in Dallas")
ans.ents
# output is (Tom, Dallas)
```

You can check the [docs](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer) to see how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

@noe Version problem now --

While loading spacy as per your syntax, I got warning -

`UserWarning: [W095] Model 'en_core_web_sm' (3.5.0) was trained with spaCy v3.5 and may not be 100% compatible with the current version (3.4.4). If you see errors or degraded performance, download a newer compatible model or retrain your custom model with the current spaCy version.`

I tried to do pip3 uninstall spacy to check my current spacy version in system path. It is indeed 3.4.4 and it gave this output -

```
Found exiting installation: spacy 3.4.4 Uninstalling spacy-3.4.4: 
Would remove: c:\Users\k******\appdata\roaming\python\python310\scripts\spacy.exe c:\Users\k******\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\spacy-3.4.4.dist-info\* c:\Users\k******\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages\spacy\* Proceed (Y/n)?
```

Even if I wanted to use the above spacy 3.4.4; its folders (scripts, site-packages) structure is very different from folder structure of C:\Users\Desktop\en_core_web_sm-3.5.0.

The 'tuple error' issue occurs on my current installation of spacy 3.5.

Thanks

Comment: The code I show you works perfectly with Spacy 3.6.1. How did you install Spacy and the model? Also, please don't add information in the form of another answer to your own question; instead, you can update your question with further info and add a comment.